# Best way to interrupt, save, and continue later with a loop

Tags: r, loops

Here is the thing. I have a loop that takes several days to run. I want to interrupt the loop, check progress, and continue later. Currently, I am using the following:

```
for (i in 1:100000) {
  Sys.sleep(i*2 + 5)
  print(i)
  write.csv(i, "i.csv")
}
```

I check the value of `i` each time and change the starting point of the loop accordingly. Are there formal and better ways to do this?

Comment: Does the loop have a definite output? If all it is doing is writing CSV files, I would be looking at the folder it is writing to and seeing what the latest csv to be written is. That way, you don't need to interrupt the loop at all.

Comment: @AllanCameron It's only writing one .csv, though.

Comment: If this is not a mistake in your code, you rewrite the entire .csv in each iteration which is quite inefficient. Maybe you want just append a row, try `write.table(append=TRUE)` for that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45931103/6574038

Comment: If you are on Linux you can use the criu command (see https://criu.org) to checkpint and restore.  Another approach is to run R in a virtual machine and hibernate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop instead. This has the advantage, that the iterator won't start always from the beginning, but resumes at it's current value. So you should be able to interrupt the loop, check the .csv, and resume then.

```
i <- 1
iter <- 4
while (i <= iter) {
  cat(i, '\n')
  Sys.sleep(i)
  write.csv(i, "i.csv", row.names=FALSE)
  i <- i + 1
}
# 1 
# 2 
# 3 
# 4 

read.csv("i.csv")
#   x
# 1 4
```

In case you want to append a row instead of rewriting the entire .csv in each iteration, try `write.table`.

```
j <- 1
iter <- 4
while (j <= iter) {
  cat(j, '\n')
  Sys.sleep(j)
  write.table(j, file="./j.csv", append=TRUE, sep=',',
              row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
  j <- j + 1
}
# 1 
# 2 
# 3 
# 4 

read.csv("j.csv", header=FALSE)
#   V1
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# 4  4
```