# Saving the Output of a Loop Every "X" Seconds

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, time

I want to make a loop that saves the results of the loop to your computer every "x" seconds. For example, consider the following loop:

```
my_list <- list()

for (i in 1:10000000) {
  a_i <- rnorm(1, 100, 100)
  my_list[[i]] <- a_i
  saveRDS(my_list, "my_list.RDS")
}
```

I want to make it so that the "saveRDS" command is executed every 33 seconds, thus overwriting the previous version of the file.

I know that the "Sys.time()" function can be used to record time in R and "Sys.sleep()" can be used to pause time - but I am not sure how it can be used to use these functions together  to perform this task.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Weird, I've answered a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73846030/6574038) a minute before. Is this an assignment?

Comment: What a coincidence! I will look your answer there! I am trying to run a big webscrape ... and my computer shuts down every few hours and I lose all my progress  ... I had this idea that if I could save my results every hour ... I could restart at the last saved checkpoint and save my work... kind of like carrying groceries in from the car... better two bags at a time and slowly, instead of all bags at once and everything falls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the loop to do stuff every x seconds, set `Sys.sleep` at the end, i.e. before the next iteration starts. The time might get longer, if the "stuff" to be done needs long time. Here my proposal:

```
my_list <- list()

for (i in 1:5) {
  tm <- Sys.time()
  ## do stuff
  my_list[[i]] <- tm
  saveRDS(my_list, "my_list.RDS")
  Sys.sleep(3)  ## actually 33 secs
}

readRDS("my_list.RDS")
# [[1]]
# [1] "2022-09-25 19:37:26 CEST"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2022-09-25 19:37:29 CEST"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "2022-09-25 19:37:32 CEST"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "2022-09-25 19:37:35 CEST"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "2022-09-25 19:37:38 CEST"
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify - I would replace "## do stuff" with the actual code, e.g.   a_i <- rnorm(1, 100, 100) ?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Yes exactly that was meant with it. I stored the time in the list as example. As we can see it's every 3 seconds as defined.

Comment: Thanks again - just a question: this code seems to be saving the "time" at which the saves are occurring. I would like to save the actual "a_i" ... should I just make this replacement?

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Not quite. I used the time measure as "doing stuff". I turned it around now: First: time is measured, then stuff is done, finally save it. Does that make sense?

Comment: just a question: it seems like this loop saves the results, goes to sleep and then resumes. So if I were to put Sys.sleep(60), I think this loop would become completely inactive for 60 seconds. Is there a way to keep the loop running, but only save the results every 60 seconds? Or is this impossible? Thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 You could try `if (i %% 100 == 0) {saveRDS(my_list, "my_list.RDS")}` to save it every 100 iterations, or do you rely on specific number of seconds? actually it's `i*33` seconds then.

Comment: I know how to do this with the index - but if you have time, can you please show me how to do this with the "time"? thank you so much!

Comment: @antonoyaro8 Iterations depend on the index not on time, use index and %%. Or ask it as new question, I have no clue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

@ Jay.sf : I made this small adjustment based on your answer and everything seems to be working now! Thank you so much!

```
my_list <- list()

for (i in 1:100000000000) {
 a_i = rnorm(1,100,100)
  tm <- Sys.time()
  my_list[[i]] <- a_i
  saveRDS(my_list, "my_list.RDS")
  Sys.sleep(5)  ## actually 33 secs
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm happy you figured it out.

Comment: This is cool, good luck!